# Docker with Node.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I'm trying to use docker with my node application, my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
RUN     apt-get update
RUN     apt-get -y install build-essential
RUN     apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN     apt-get install -y npm

ADD     . /src
RUN     cd /src && npm install

EXPOSE  8080

CMD     ["node","/src/app.js"]
```

but after running `docker build` when `npm install` is running after trying to install `https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap/-/wordwrap-0.0.2.tgz` I get an error:

```
The command 'bin/sh -c /src && npm install' returned a non-zero code : 1
```

What can cause such an issue? I've already tried to install node-legacy instead of node and it didn't work

Comment: Is the typo "regisrty" just here on SO, or is that causing your problem?

Comment: what commands did you give to build and start the image ?

Comment: the TYPO was my mistake while writing this post, I've fixed it. I'm not able to start the image as it's not building. The `npm install` returns an error after successfully installing a bunch of extra modules

Comment: would you not pass any arg to your npm install ? Is this the complete dockerfile or the partial one ? You could consider using a base image "FROM ubuntu:14.04" or something similar ... what commands did you give to build and start the image ? npm install should in one of the layers when the image is getting built.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
# put this line on your code (if you are using ubuntu)
# this make a link from nodejs to node to add compatibility on ubuntu OS
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

# set your current directory with WORKDIR
WORKDIR /src
RUN sudo npm install
```